# Delete on Eloquent doesn't delete Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a delete functionality for pictures which users can upload. The model of the picture class:

```
class Picture extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['original_file', 'resized_file'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * Get the category that owns the question.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Migration:

```
$table->timestamps();
$table->softDeletes();
```

The delete function which I have:

```
public function destroyProgress(Picture $progress){

        $progress->delete();
        dd($progress);

        return view('client.home.profile', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
    }
```

This code is executed and stoped at the `dd($progress);`. I would expect that this would return `null` because the $progress has been deleted. But this still returns an instance! Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong because I am lost for words.

Comment: The `delete` method should return `true` or `false` so you can check if the delete was successful or not. Internally though, I'm pretty sure that the model just sets the `exists` property to false to indicate that this model is no longer represented in the database, but the model itself is still intact. I would check the return value `$deleted = $progress->delete();` to see if the delete was successful, and then if so, just forget about the model.

Comment: @Jonathon Thank you for answering. I didn't think I expressed this enough in my question but the deleted_at attribute in the database is not changing as well. I added the `$deleted` and with a dd this returns `null`. I also tried `dd($progress->deleted_at)` after the `$progress->delete()` and this also returns null.

Comment: did you tried something like $pic= Picture::findOrFail($id); $pic->delete() ?

Comment: hmm wierd. no query results @sam12

Comment: no query results? normal you delete a model :). deleted_at field has been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to explain, the object `$progress` created by dependency injection is not actually a model instance. Therefore, the `delete` event will not be fired.
You should use `delete` method on a model instance:

```
$picture = App\Picture::find(1);
$picture->delete();
```

Comment: Thank you! This and changing the code in the routes to add a parameter worked for me :-)

Comment: I suspect what actually happened is that route model binding wasn't configured as expected. With route model binding that variable would have been the instance of the model in question.